# Error with a simple program, printing error (python)

Tags: python

I've only yesterday began learning about classes and tried to incorporate it into a program. After numerous tries, I finally got the last line, which prints somethings to work, but it doesn't actually say the correct thing. It says random numbers. Note that this is python.

Here is the program:

```
class Pokemon:
    def __init__(self,name,poketype):
    self.name=name
    self.poketype=poketype
    def weakness(self,poketype):
    if poketype=='fire':
        print 'strong against grass'
        print 'weak against water'
    elif poketype=='water':
        print 'strong against first'
        print 'weak against grass'
    elif poketype =='grass':
        print 'strong against water'
        print 'weak against fire'

Charmander=Pokemon('charmander','fire')
Squirtle=Pokemon('squirtle','water')
Bulbasaur=Pokemon('bulbasaur','grass')
print Carmander.weakness
```

That is supposed to print `'strong against grass'` and `'weak against water'`, but it just doesn't.

Comment: The 4 lines after the properly formatted code is also part of it...

Comment: "I finally got the last line, which prints somethings to work, but it doesn't actually say the correct thing. It says random numbers." Please add the text of errors, not just these vague reports, please.

Comment: assuming you fix the typo, `Charmander.weakness` would be the bound method and print out something like `<bound method Pokemon.weakness of <__main__.Pokemon instance at 0x10525b0e0>>` I assume the "random numbers" you are refering to is the **memory address** of the pokemon instance, I think you meant to **call the method** instead, like `Charmander.weakness()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about how code in classes work.

```
self.name = name
self.poketype = poketype
```

This code means that you will be able to access `name` and `poketype` of an instance of the class. For example, this is what I mean by "access":

```
>>> a = Pokemon('charmander', 'fire')
>>> a.name
'charmander'
>>> a.poketype
'fire'
```

So when you `def`ine a function that needs more than one argument (`self`), it actually means that thte function takes in more inputs. In other words this code:

```
def weakness(self, poketype):
    if poketype == 'fire':
        print 'strong against grass'
        print 'weak against water'

    elif poketype == 'water':
        print 'strong against first'
        print 'weak against grass'

    elif poketype == 'grass':
        print 'strong against water'
        print 'weak against fire'
```

Will be run as:

```
>>> a = Pokemon('charmander', 'fire')
>>> a.weakness("passing in the poketype argument here")
```

Which is not what you want. What you want is that no arguemnt needs to be passed in and it will just spit out an output. So, you just need the `self` argument.

```
def weakness(self):
    if poketype == 'fire':
        print 'strong against grass'
        print 'weak against water'

    elif poketype == 'water':
        print 'strong against first'
        print 'weak against grass'

    elif poketype == 'grass':
        print 'strong against water'
        print 'weak against fire'
```

Now you would ask: How do I get the `poketype` then? The answer is simple: You just access it like you would outside of the class, except, you use `self` instead of the variable name.

```
def weakness(self):
    if self.poketype == 'fire':
        print 'strong against grass'
        print 'weak against water'

    elif self.poketype == 'water':
        print 'strong against first'
        print 'weak against grass'

    elif self.poketype == 'grass':
        print 'strong against water'
        print 'weak against fire'
```

And that's it! You're done! The final code:

```
class Pokemon:
    def __init__(self, name, poketype):
        self.name = name
        self.poketype = poketype

    def weakness(self):
        if self.poketype == 'fire':
            print 'strong against grass'
            print 'weak against water'

        elif self.poketype == 'water':
            print 'strong against first'
            print 'weak against grass'

        elif self.poketype == 'grass':
            print 'strong against water'
            print 'weak against fire'

Charmander = Pokemon('charmander','fire')
Squirtle = Pokemon('squirtle','water')
Bulbasaur = Pokemon('bulbasaur','grass')

# Note the empty parentheses, if you miss them out, you are just referring to
# the function but not calling it!
>>> Charmander.weakness()
strong against grass
weak against water
```

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations and step by step guides on what I got wrong. I've recently started classes and obviously didn't learn about some 'concepts'...

Answer (score 0):

you must pass a `poketype` parameter in `weakness` function

Comment: No, there should be no `poketype` parameter, and `self.poketype` should be referenced instead.

Comment: in that case, remove `poketype` from your function. try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
If (self.poketype == 'fire')
```

It doesn't know what poketype with the way you passed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working class. You had a couple of mistakes:

- The primary problem was that you were initializing but not utilizing your instance variables. The entire point of instance variables is to avoid having to pass endless numbers of variables between methods as arguments if all of the methods are closely related. To fix that, you need to use `self.poketype` instead of just `poketype` throughout the entire `weakness` method.
- Additionally, you had a presumed typo in the last line where you wrote `Carmander` instead of `Charmander` (no big deal).
- Penultimately, you were not actually invoking `Charmander`'s `weakness` method because you left out the parentheses. Without the parentheses, the actual `Pokemon.weakness` function will be returned.
- Finally, you should have your class inherit from `object` regardless of whether you are using Python 2.x or Python 3.x. This is just considered good practice.

```
class Pokemon(object):
    def __init__(self, name, poketype):
        self.name = name
        self.poketype = poketype

    def weakness(self):
        if self.poketype == 'fire':
            print 'strong against grass'
            print 'weak against water'

        elif self.poketype == 'water':
            print 'strong against first'
            print 'weak against grass'

        elif self.poketype == 'grass':
            print 'strong against water'
            print 'weak against fire'

Charmander = Pokemon('charmander','fire')
Squirtle = Pokemon('squirtle','water')
Bulbasaur = Pokemon('bulbasaur','grass')

print Charmander.weakness()
```

Comment: Please include explanations

Comment: Thank you. This code worked well. I'm going to try to extend this into a game now

Answer (score 0):

From your `print` statement syntax, I'm assuming you are using Python 2.x.

According to your current definition of the function, your print statements are called within the function. Therefore, simply change the last line to:

```
Charmander.weakness('fire')
```

Which returns the output:

```
strong against grass
weak against water
```

The reason for this is that your `weakness` method takes `poketype` as a parameter. Alternatively, you can define the `weakness` method as `def weakness(self):` and then call it as `Charmander.weakness()`.